# MStest all test cases are skipped .net application

Tags: c#, .net, mstest, vs-unit-testing-framework

MStest all test cases are skipped .net application. Almost 3000 unit test cases are written all test cases ar skipped and even debug points are not hitting. Collogues running the same application successfully. I am using Visual Studio 2019. New projects MSTest working fine. I deleted .vs folder and updated VS studio. Platform target Any CPU and x64 also tried.

Comment: is it dotnet core or dotnet framework? check .csproj file for TargetFramework tag. also check if Assert.Inconclusive() is used in the test methods.

Comment: Dotnet  framework project. Target framework is 4.8. Inconclusive not used.

Comment: have you tried running tests from terminal/cmd? more info here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test
not much familiar with .net framework, are you in the right directory? is build successful? also, pls check if all the packages/references are compatible with your version of framework (see manage nuget packages).